# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in RDotNet.dll

Tags: c#, mysql, r

Context: The below piece of code is working fine with C# windows app when come to MVC Web App it's throwing an Exception "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in RDotNet.dll", I am using RDotnet v1.6.5

```
    string rScriptFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RScriptFilePath"].ToString();
    var envPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");var rBinPath = System.Environment.Is64BitProcess ? @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x64" : @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\bin\i386";
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", envPath + Path.PathSeparator + rBinPath);
    engine = REngine.GetInstance();
    engine.Initialize();
    string execRScriptPath = "source(\"" + rScriptFilePath + "\", encoding = \"Windows-1252\")";
    engine.Evaluate(execRScriptPath);

and my R script file contains the below code to get Data from MYSQL DB 'Users' table and and load data into the same DB "testTable10" table

    if (!require("DT")) install.packages('DT')
    if (!require("DBI")) install.packages('DBI')
    if (!require("RMySQL")) install.packages('RMySQL')
    library(DT)
    library(DBI)
    library(RMySQL)

    mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'userName', password = 'password', dbname = 'SomeDb', host = 'localhost')
    dbListTables(mydb)
    dbListFields(mydb, 'Users')
    rs = dbSendQuery(mydb, "select Id,Code,Name from Users")
    data = fetch(rs, n = -1)
    dbWriteTable(mydb, "testTable10", data)
    datatable(data) 

    Please help me to solve this problem....!
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solution 1**

I had the same problem with moving R.Net from console app to a MVC WebApp.

The problem was that a library I used plotted charts next to the numbers by default.
When it comes to such a plot function a StackOverflow-Exception was thrown.

On MVC no GDI ressources can be accessed. **Please check if some of the functions you use require / uses GDI functions**. After disabling the graphical outputs with graph = FALSE on the function I used, it was working on MVC. Maybe there is a similar options on your side.

---

**Possible Solution 2**

Even with disabling the graph output, my r code runs successfully only the first time. On a second run the Stackoverflow-Exception occurs again. **After switching to R-Open from Microsoft (https://mran.microsoft.com/open) it is working now** without any exceptions multiple times :)